# Is there a way to find out which pytest-xdist gateway is running?

Tags: pytest, pytest-xdist

I would like to create a separate log file for each subprocess/gateway that is spawned by pytest-xdist. Is there an elegant way of finding out in which subprocess/gateway pytest is currently in? I'm configuring my root logger with a session scoped fixture located in `conftest.py`, something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def setup_logging():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    fh = logging.FileHandler('xdist.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
   fh.setFormatter(formatter)

   logger.addHandler(fh)
```

It would be great if i could add a prefix to the log file name based on the gateway number, e.g:

```
 fh = logging.FileHandler('xdist_gateway_%s.log' % gateway_number)
```

Without this each gateway will use the same log and the logs will get messy. I know that I can add a time stamp to the filename. But this doesn't let me to distinguish quickly which file is from which gateway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that you can access the gateway id in the following way:

```
slaveinput = getattr(session.config, "slaveinput", None)

if slaveinput:
    gatewayid = slaveinput['slaveid']
```

Of course you need to be in a place where you can access the session.config object.

Comment: Just note that 'slaveinput' is changed to 'workerinput' in xdist 2.0.0+

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [@Kanguros's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24573397/884640) but plugging into the pytest fixture paradigm:

> You can get the worker id by [accessing] the slaveinput dictionary. Here's a fixture which makes that information available to tests and other fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def worker_id(request):
    if hasattr(request.config, 'workerinput'):
        return request.config.workerinput['workerid']
    else:
        return 'master'
```

This is quoted from [a comment on the pytest-xdist Issues tracker/discussion](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/47#issuecomment-187891183) (2016).